# AWS OpsWorks Chef 11 Multiple Databases

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, aws-opsworks

I would like to know how to prevent OpsWorks **sym-linking** `database.yml`. And instead use the `database.yml` file included in the Github Ruby on Rails app repository?

If not possible I would like to know what is the JSON syntax for adding a primary and secondary database to a stack.

**It works with a single DB**

```
        "database": {
            "host": "...",
            "database": "...",
            "username": "...",
            "password": "...",
            "adapter": "postgresql",
            "port": 5432,
            "pool": 100,
            "encoding": "utf8"
        },
```

**Not Working With Primary and Secondary**

```
  "database": {
    "primary": {
      "host": "...",
      "database": "...",
      "username": "...",
      "password": "...",
      "adapter": "postgresql",
      "port": 5432,
      "pool": 100,
      "encoding": "utf8"
    },
    "secondary": {
      "host": "...",
      "database": "...",
      "username": "...",
      "password": "...",
      "replica": true,
      "adapter": "postgresql",
      "port": 5432,
      "pool": 100,
      "encoding": "utf8"
    }
  }
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution**

Note: Ensure database configuration and repository information are private.

1. Copy `./config/database.yml` to `./config/database.bak.yml`
2. Add the following to `config/application.rb`

   ```
   config.paths["config/database"] = "./config/database.bak.yml"
   ```